# Get JSON node if results exist

Tags: php, json

I need to get the values for a JSON node based on if the value exists

I figured out how to detect if the flavor exists in the JSON, now I just need to get all of the information inside that node

```
$flav = $_GET['flav'];
$json = '[{
    "flavor": "chocolate",
    "type": "hard",
    "instock": true
}, {
    "flavor": "vanilla",
    "type": "hard"
    "instock": false
}, {
    "flavor": "strawberry",
    "type:" "soft"
    "instock": true
}, {
    "flavor": "mint",
    "type": "hard"
    "instock": true
}]';
$decode = json_decode($json);
if(in_array($flav, array_column($decode, 'flavor'))) {
  print flavor . ' - ' . type . ' - ' . instock;
} else {
  print 'Invalid flavor';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your JSON, so I've corrected those and the main problem is that you use `in_array()` which just tells you it is in the array and not where.  So in the first version I've changed this to `array_search()` which then tells you where it is.

```
$flav = $_GET['flav'];
$json = '[{
    "flavor": "chocolate",
    "type": "hard",
    "instock": true
}, {
    "flavor": "vanilla",
    "type": "hard",
    "instock": false
}, {
    "flavor": "strawberry",
    "type" : "soft",
    "instock": true
}, {
    "flavor": "mint",
    "type": "hard",
    "instock": true
}]';
$decode = json_decode($json);
if(($key = array_search($flav, array_column($decode, 'flavor'))) !== false) {
    print "flavor - ". $decode[$key]->flavor.PHP_EOL
        . "type - ". $decode[$key]->type.PHP_EOL
        . "instock - ". $decode[$key]->instock.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    print 'Invalid flavor';
}
```

I've also done a second version which re-indexes the array with flavor as the index and so you can directly access it...

```
// Decode to an array
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
// Create a new version of the array indexed by the flavor
$decode = array_column($decode, null, "flavor");
// Check if it is in the array
if ( isset ($decode[$flav]) ){
    // Directly output the data
    print "flavor - ". $decode[$flav]["flavor"].PHP_EOL
        . "type - ". $decode[$flav]["type"].PHP_EOL
        . "instock - ". $decode[$flav]["instock"].PHP_EOL;
} else {
    print 'Invalid flavor';
}
```

Comment: Also, thanks for telling me what I did wrong instead of just posting code :D